# Can I use UpdatePanel in MasterPage to wrap nested pages?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajax.net

Can I use Update panel in masterpage to wrap nested pages so that when browsing from one page to the other client only gets a partial refresh (MasterPage doesn't get reloaded).

If so - how? Do I Just put an update panel around the `ContentPlaceholder` in the Master Page?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**I do not advise you to wrap an entire page in an `UpdatePanel`**, for the following reasons:

- If you want your site to be index by Search Engines, you will need to **display your content on separate pages**...just having a different querystring on each content section is enough.  This is because for search engines **Content Is King** and since search engines currently cannot index dynamically generated data, they will not be able to index your pages.
- **Wrapping entire pages in an `Update Panel` is very dangerous** because of the **huge overhead that is sent to the server**.  You will see a significant performance decrease if you do so.  Read [this article](http://encosia.com/2007/07/11/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/) for more information on the subject
- Because of this huge overhead, it is suggested to use the `Update Panel` to **update just small sections of the website** (like little box widgets on the side, etc...) and not whole content sections.
- Wrapping content sections in an update panel means that you will have to go the extra mile dynamically changing the url (using # anchors) manually yourself, and this is so that you will give users the ability to use the back button on their browser to go to the previous section of the site.  **Not having the ability to go back in a page is very annoying for users**

---

Here is an example that demonstrates the problem with `UpdatePanel`s.
The following is code for a simple aspx page with a label and a button :

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="up1">
 <ContentTemplate>
   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" Text="Update Me!" /><br />
   <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" 
     Text="Postback Update" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
 </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
}
```

And the following is a partial postback done with the `UpdatePanel` when the button is clicked (notice the huge overhead involved) : 
                  [image]
<sub>(source: [encosia.com](http://encosia.com/blog/media/images/updatepanel-payload-response-sm.png))</sub>

As you can see, the server is basically sending all the elements that are in the `UpdatePanel` back to the client.

---

On the other hand, here is an example that involves using [ASP.Net Page Methods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/).  Notice the response sent from the server this time (*no UpdatePanels involved*) :

[image]
<sub>(source: [encosia.com](http://encosia.com/blog/media/images/json-payload-response.png))</sub>

Comment: the article is very interesting as well - problem is people are lazy :-)

Comment: Very much informative. Took many articles to understand the overhead involved with UpdatePanel. Thanks a lot!!!